# Integration by parts giving two different answers

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to evaluate the following integral,

$$
\int_0^1 x \exp(2\pi ix)dx.
$$

An online integral calculator gave the value as $-\frac{i}{2\pi}$. But, if I integrate by parts, then I get,

$$
\int_0^1 x \exp(2\pi ix)dx = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \left[x\exp(2\pi ix)\right]_0^1 - \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_0^1\exp(2\pi i x)dx = 0.
$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: how do you get $0$? It is $\frac{1}{2\pi i}[1-0]-\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2}[1-1] = \frac{1}{2\pi i}=\frac{-i}{2\pi}$

Comment: Ah yes! simple calculation mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\exp(0) = \exp(2\pi i) = 1$, so

$$
\left.\frac{x\exp(2\pi i x)}{2\pi i}\right|_0^1 = \frac{1 - 0}{2\pi i} = -\frac{i}{2\pi}
$$